# coroutine needs to be awaited in asyncio.ensure_future() - asyncio

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, python-asyncio

I need to run a coroutine in a loop.
So, I created a new loop, then I created a task with `asyncio.ensure_future(awatable, loop)`, last, I ran the task through the loop thanks to `loop.run_forever(task)`.
However, when I launch the script, I receive an error telling me that the coroutine was never awaited. How is that possible? The first argument of `ensure_future()` is an awaitable and does not need to be awaited, does it? Moreover, it tells me that I destroyed a pending task, but did I?

## Code

```py
async def initiate_bot():
    await bot.add_cog(my_commands.MusicBot(bot, prefix, float(volume), lyrics, bot_name, spotify_id, spotify_secret))
    await bot.start(token)


# create loop
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
# create a task
task = asyncio.ensure_future(initiate_bot(), loop=loop)
try:
    # task runs forever
    loop.run_forever(task)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    # stop and close loop
    loop.stop()
    sys.exit(0)
```

## Error:

`Task was destroyed but it is pending! task: <Task pending name='Task-1' coro=<initiate_bot() running at /home/[user]/Scrivania/Coding/[project name]/main.py:45>> sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'initiate_bot' was never awaited`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [loop.run_forever()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_forever) function does not take any arguments. When you use [asyncio.ensure_future()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.ensure_future) you are already scheduling the task for execution.

Python 3.7 introduced a new helper function [asyncio.run()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-runner.html#asyncio.run) which automatically creates and destroys the asynchronous event loop. So, you can simply replace your code with:

```py
async def initiate_bot():
    await bot.add_cog(my_commands.MusicBot(bot, prefix, float(volume), lyrics, bot_name, spotify_id, spotify_secret))
    await bot.start(token)


asyncio.run(initiate_bot())
```